# does bootstrap grid emit an event when it is finished layout?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to detect the size of a div that is inside a bootstrap grid layout.
Currently I am listening for window resize events like below, and then querying the DOM to find the div size

`window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);`

```
updateDimensions() {
    // find the actual width of the parent element
    let cbb = document.querySelector('.App-component-inner').getBoundingClientRect();
    let cwidth = cbb.right - cbb.left;
    // console.log("cwidth " + cwidth);

    if (this.state.width !== cwidth) {
        this.setState({
            bb: cbb,
            width: cwidth
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that bootstrap grid is still performing layout when the `updateDimensions()` function is called.
So I would like to know if there is an event that Bootstrap Grid emits when it finishes its layout?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" in case anyone else was searching for the answer.